# Android Studio Screen shot Option FAILS

Tags: android, android-studio, screenshot

Im trying to take screen shot of my **Emulator** .

1. I run my **app**.
2. Then switched to **Android Device Monitor Screen**.
3. In Device panel I clicked my **online Emulator**(Nexus5[emulator-5554]) in which my app is running.
4. To take screen shot of my app i pressed the screen shot **Camera button**.

   [image]
5. Faced an error with empty **X** screen

[image]

Here is my **LogCat error**

```
10-04 23:07:41.008: E/gralloc_goldfish(923): gralloc_alloc: Mismatched usage flags: 1080 x 1920, usage 333
10-04 23:07:41.008: W/GraphicBufferAllocator(923): alloc(1080, 1920, 1, 00000333, ...) failed -22     (Invalid argument)
10-04 23:07:41.008: E/(923): GraphicBufferAlloc::createGraphicBuffer(w=1080, h=1920) failed (Invalid argument), handle=0x0
10-04 23:07:41.018: E/BufferQueue(3045): [ScreenshotClient] dequeueBuffer: SurfaceComposer::createGraphicBuffer failed
```

please help me with this issue..**Thanks**

Comment: Rather than use Android Debug Monitor, try taking the screenshot straight from Android Studio, using the camera toolbar button in the DDMS view.

Comment: @CommonsWare Wow..!! Another option.!! i'll try that.. Thanks for showing another way to achieve this :) but, what about this above problem.. any solution ..?

Comment: My hope is that Android Studio and the Android Debug Monitor are conflicting and causing your issue. If that is not the problem, I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: Is the emulator using host GPU? This could be the cause.